# VS2010 Debug and Release Clean and Rebuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have one project (in c/c++ ) which consist of two solutions.
First one is "build_model", another is "fit_model".
I set up properties to put all binaries in the same directory as "fit_model" will invoke during it's execution "build_model".

So, I first compile "build_model" and it goes well. All files are put into .../bin\
Then I compile "fit_model"  and it is OK as well. All files are put into .../bin\
Everything works fine.
Even if do "Clean" and "Rebuild" for "fit_model" only it's binaries are deleted are re-created.
That is for Release build.
Clean & Re-build of "build_model" also cleans only it's own binaries (as it should be).

But when I switch to Debug mode, as soon as I do Clean for "fit_model" it deletes all of the binaries in .../bin\ folder, including it's own and binaries from "build_model".
This is NOT what I want.

So, this is not happening in Release, but only for Debug clean & rebuild.

Which settings should I change?

(VS2010, Windows7)

EDIT: The problem is that even with different directories it does the same. Also, adding "d" and "r" for debug and release to $(ProjectDir) won't do the trick.

I don't know how it finds the path at all? There is **bin** directory with two subdirectories: **fit** and **build**

So how it comes that Clean for Solution fit_model "cleans" **build** directory besides his own **fit** as well?

Comment: This is why, by default, VS uses *different* directories for the Release and Debug build output.  Just do the same thing.

Comment: The problem is that even with different directories it does the same. That was the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do the sensible thing and use different directories, [like Hans suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419319/vs2010-debug-and-release-clean-and-rebuild#comment27059591_18419319), then you'll need to change the name of the output files.

In your project's properties window (Configuration Properties → General), there is a property called "Target Name". It defaults to the name of your project. You need to change it to something *different* in your debug and release builds.

You can do something simple like adding a `d` to the end of the name for the debug version. For example, `$(ProjectName)d` will automatically pick up the project's name.

Comment: The problem is that even with different directories it does the same. That was the first thing I tried.